# AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice returns nil for some users

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am using device's camera to click some pictures. The below code is working fine for almost 90% of the users but it is crashing for the remaining ones.

```
_session = [AVCaptureSession new];
_session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;

//
// setup device
//

AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

if ([device lockForConfiguration:nil]) {
    if (device.autoFocusRangeRestrictionSupported) {
        device.autoFocusRangeRestriction = AVCaptureAutoFocusRangeRestrictionNear;
    }

    if (device.smoothAutoFocusSupported) {
        device.smoothAutoFocusEnabled = YES;
    }

    if([device isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus]){
        device.focusMode = AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus;
    }

    device.exposureMode = AVCaptureExposureModeContinuousAutoExposure;

    [device unlockForConfiguration];
}

//
// add device input to session
//

AVCaptureDeviceInput *deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:nil];
[_session addInput:deviceInput];
```

From crash logs it says [AVCaptureSession addInput:] Can't add a nil AVCaptureInput which basically means deviceInput object is coming up to be nil for some users. Can anyone please help me with the root cause for this or in which scenarios this object could be nil as it is working perfectly fine for majority of the users.

Comment: try to check for `authorizationStatusForMediaType` .. for `availableCameraDevices`... add deviceInput only if is not nil... more here https://www.objc.io/issues/21-camera-and-photos/camera-capture-on-ios/

Comment: According to the documentation for this method, it looks like this could happen if the device is no longer available or in use:

Comment: It's possible the user granted camera access to your app, started scanning, then rejected permission, and attempted to start scanning again. Another possibility is they were using the camera in another app and quickly switched over to yours, not giving the camera enough time to unlock for use.

Comment: If user has started scanning and then rejected permission then iOS forces the app to restart hence crash is not possible in this case.